# How to search for a specific pattern in a string using regrex

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a specific pattern  `name` in the below string using regrex. The `name` occur after the `selfie_`

for example:

name = OKAH_AGHOLOR

`url = 'https://ignite-api.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/live/selfie_OKAH_AGHOLOR_22342028078-IND-1619350764067.jpeg'`

I have tried the below regrex expression

```
pattern = re.compile(r'_[A-Za-z_]+')
sequence = url
pattern.search(sequence).group()
```

output:

```
'_OKAH_AGHOLOR_'
```

Comment: I just wanted to stop by and say that is a beautiful selfie. Love the hat!

Comment: @PacketLoss smiles. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookarounds so the `_` at the beginning and end are not included in the match.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=_)[a-z_]+(?=_)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Exactly the output I expected. Thanks